# Django admin display multiple fields on the same line

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have created a model, it will automatically display all the fields from the model and display it on the admin page.

Now, I have a problem, I would like to have two fields on the same line, to do this I have to specify the fieldsets at ModelAdmin:

```
fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': (('firstname', 'lastname'),)
        }),
       )
```

**Do I have to specify all the fields?** Because there are many fields in the database I need to specify.

Comment: Just an idea at the top of my head. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3106295/257972) tells how to get a list of model fields. Take a list of all fields and remove `firstname, lastname` using `set difference`

Answer (score 45):

Wrap those fields on their own tuple.

```
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = (
        'field1',
        ('field2', 'field3'),
        'field4'
    )
```

In the above example, fields `field2` and `field3` are shown on one line.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there's not an easy way to do it.

One option is to override the change_form.html template for that ModelAdmin and style the form as you like.

Another alternative is to do custom ModelForm and define a field with a widget that renders two input fields, in the form's .save() method, set the widget resulting value (a tuple) to both fields.

Comment: Thanks, I am finding something easier.

Answer (score 2):

There is an article may be useful

http://amk1.wordpress.com/2010/09/23/a-2-column-django-admin-form/

Article is quote below:

---

> Django is great. The bundled admin interface makes it better. But as the number of items on the form gets bigger, the amount of wasted space increases because the layout is single column. Coupled with left alignment on wide-screen monitors, my users usually end their day with a condition we call “eyeballs misalignment”.
>
> So I improvised and changed the form (and StackedInline) to a 2-up layout. No more “eyeballs misalignment”.
>
> The corresponding template for Django 1.2.1 (/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html) looks like this, modified lines highlighted:
>
> ```
> <fieldset class="module aligned {{ fieldset.classes }}">
>     {% if fieldset.name %}<h2>{{ fieldset.name }}</h2>{% endif %}
>     {% if fieldset.description %}
>         <div class="description">{{ fieldset.description|safe }}</div>
>     {% endif %}
>     <table border=0 width=100%>
>     {% for line in fieldset %}
>         {% cycle '<tr>' '' %}
>         <td width=50%>
>         <div style="border-bottom:0" class="form-row{% if line.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% for field in line %} {{ field.field.name }}{% endfor %}">
>             {{ line.errors }}
>             {% for field in line %}
>                 <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:"1" %} class="field-box"{% endif %}>
>                     {% if field.is_checkbox %}
>                         {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
>                     {% else %}
>                         {{ field.label_tag }}
>                         {% if field.is_readonly %}
>                             <p>{{ field.contents }}</p>
>                         {% else %}
>                             {{ field.field }}
>                         {% endif %}
>                     {% endif %}
>                     {% if field.field.field.help_text %}
>                         <p class="help">{{ field.field.field.help_text|safe }}</p>
>                     {% endif %}
>                 </div>
>             {% endfor %}
>         </div>
>         </td>
>         {% cycle '' '</tr>' %}
>     {% endfor %}
>     </table>
> </fieldset>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

this has worked for me

```
fieldsets=(        
       ("My Group",{"fields": (tuple(['field1','field1']),),}), 
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

It's stupid, but yes, if you're going to use the `fieldsets` tuple-within-a-tuple method, you have to then specify all the fields that should show on your form.

Comment: It is actually the *sad* answer to the question "Do I have to specify all the fields? "

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, that its annoying, but its tuple of tuples from list of fields.
you can use list comprehension and change list to tuple.
Here is an example for skipping some fields, that you want to give some special attention WHILE including rest normal way.

```
skipped=[]
alist = [field.name for field in <model_name>._meta.fields if field.name not in skipped]
fieldsets = tuple(alist)
*** play with skipped ***
```

with small tweaking this should work.