# How to show multiple fields within a row? (Django Admin)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I've been struggling with a situation in Django/Mysql.

There is this column in a table that has a primary key and foreign key at the same time. This column has a one to many relation with an intermediary table.

It's a list of states linked to plant species. Some species can be found in more than one state.

- Species (table 1) Columns: Species_id | specie_name
- Species_to_states (table 2) Columns: Species_id | State_id
- States (table 3) Columns: States_id, State_name

**Models.py (code below)**

```
class Listaflor(models.Model):
    especie = models.OneToOneField(Flora2Estado, models.DO_NOTHING, primary_key=True)
class Flora2Estado(models.Model):
    estado = models.OneToOneField(Estados, models.DO_NOTHING, primary_key=True)
    especie = models.ForeignKey('Listaflor', models.DO_NOTHING)
class Estados(models.Model):
    estado_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    estado_nome = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    nome_abbr = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    criadoem = models.DateTimeField(db_column='criadoEm')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'estados'
        verbose_name = "Estados"
        verbose_name_plural = "Estado"
    def str(self):
        return self.estado_nome+ " (" + self.nome_abbr+")"
```

**The point is that only one object is being displayin django admin (check the image below). So i would like to show multiple fields within a row.**

[image]

Can someone help me with that?

Thank you so much

```
class floAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('especie','familia','regiaopred','emailautor','aprovado','datacriado','especie_0')
    fieldsets = (
        ('Editar:', {
            'fields': (

                'especie','familia','regiaopred','emailautor','aprovado','datacriado','especie_0'
                #'pes_vinculo_tipo'
                )
            }),
        )
```

Just like the image below, I want to display "Miami, Ny and Maine", for example, in only one row in django admin. Is that possible?

[image]

Comment: I'm confused... why do you have `Listaflor.especie` as a `OneToOne` field to `Flora2Estado` and also have `Flora2Estado.especie`  as a `ForeignKey` to `Listaflor`?

Comment: Can you share your Admin model please?

Comment: @Chris So do I just have to set oneToMany on listaflor.especie?

Comment: Thank you both for your attention!

Comment: @Jay, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. But yes, it's unusual to have both of these relationships set up.

Comment: @Chris , Ok, sorry. I did what you told me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @tarasinf, I've edited my question and inserted the code you asked me. Thanks.

Comment: @Chris , I want to display "State_Name" (column: estado_name - table: estados) within (table listaflor) in  Django Admin ... 

The point is that we could have more than one state name for a single specie (Column: especie | table: listaflor)  . That's why we have that intermediary table flora2estado.

So, I would like to display multiple "estados" on a row listaflor table in Django Admin
..

Sorry about my english. I hope I was more clear this time.

Comment: @Chris , I've edit my initial question once again. Since my english is causing me trouble, I 've drawn a table with exemples. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what info you want to get in a cell, but want to suggest you to use the next approach:

```
class floAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('especie', 'familia', 'regiaopred', 'emailautor', 'aprovado', 'datacriado', 'especie_0', 'custom_field', )
    fieldsets = (
        ('Editar:', {
            'fields': ('especie', 'familia', 'regiaopred', 'emailautor', 'aprovado', 'datacriado', 'especie_0', 'custom_field', )
            }),
        )

    def custom_field(self, obj):
        data_list_to_show = []  # get data based on obj
        return data_list_to_show
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your suggestion. 
What exactly should i put into the data_list_to_show?
I want to display multiple "estado_nome" in the same row. 

Once again, thank you so much for your time.

Comment: in `data_list_to_show` you should put those multiple "estado_nome" objects (id, or link to object, anything you need).

Comment: I've edit my initial question once again. Since my english is causing me trouble, I 've drawn a table with exemples. Thank you so much.

Comment: I've tried the code you suggested : 

def custom_field(self, obj):
        data_list_to_show = [Estados.estado_nome],

The following message is being displayed in admin:

<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x03E2EFB8>

Comment: Your AdminModel class should be related to specific DjangoModel, what is that model in your case?
You can't do like this `[Estados.estado_nome]`, here you try to get class property, where you need to use object property, please try to get all info you need from `obj`.

Answer (score 1):

If I true understood) because I had the same problem. This helped me:

```
fieldsets=(        
       ("My Group",{"fields": (tuple(['field1','field1']),),}), 
    )
```

Wrap those fields on their own tuple. There  was answer [Django admin display multiple fields on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852540/django-admin-display-multiple-fields-on-the-same-line)