# Exclude field from values() or values_list()

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

Is there an efficient way to exclude fields from the function `values()` or `values_list`.

e.g

```
Videos.objects.filter(id=1).get().values()
```

I want to exclude from this queryset the field `duration`.

I know that I can specify fields what I want to have in the result but what if I want everything but only one field not. Like in the cases if I have 20 fields and if I want only one from them not.

Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You must use [`defer`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#defer) This will not add defined fields to  your `select` query.

```
Videos.objects.filter(...).defer('duration')
```

Comment: Before using `defer()`, read the [note in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#defer): it's intended for advanced use-cases.

Comment: Note that the question was "how to exclude fields from values() or values_list()". Calling one of those two methods after calling `defer` will still contain the deferred field.

Example :
`MyObject.objects.defer("created_at").values().first()["created_at"]`
returns
`datetime.datetime(...)`
when you would expect a `KeyError`

Answer (score 20):

You can get all fields first, then pop out the fields you do not want:

```
fields = Video._meta.get_all_field_names()
fields.remove('id')
Video.object.filter(...).values(*fields)
```

Comment: To get the field names directly you can use: ``Video._meta.get_all_field_names()``

Comment: The `get_all_field_names()` method was deprecated some time ago and removed. Now you have to do: `[f.name for f in Video._meta.get_fields()]`, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3106314/4744341