# Excluding fields while using Values()

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a model `XYZ(name,age,sex)`,
I am fetching all the fields using `XYZ.objects.filter(name='ddd').values()`
this is returning all the fields in `dict`. How to exclude the field `age`?

I have tried the following, but it not working

```
XYZ.objects.filter(name='').exclude('sex').values()
```

Comment: Put all list of fields into `values` exclude is not for selector it is for filter.

Comment: Thank you but In my real model i have 48 attributes so is their any way i can do it without naming each one of them

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854659/exclude-field-from-values-or-values-list

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
XYZ.objects.filter(name='ddd').defer('age')      

OR

XYZ.objects.values('name','sex').filter(name='ddd')

OR 

fields = XYZ._meta.get_fields() # Try
fields.remove('age')
XYZ.object.filter(name='ddd').values(*fields)

OR

fields = list(XYZ._meta.get_fields())
fieldslist = [field.name for field in fields]  
XYZ.object.filter(name='ddd').values(*fieldslist)
```

Put all list of fields into values exclude is not for selector it is for filter.

Comment: Thank you but In my real model i have 48 attributes so is their any way i can do it without naming each one of them @anup yadav

Comment: use this `XYZ._meta.get_fields()` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/meta/

Comment: How filters and ._meta you are trying together? This is just to get list of fields to add in select of Django ORM