# Paginating a context inside a DetailView in Django

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have an Asset Detail View that uses data from another two models, Tenant and Service.

**asset\views.py**

```
class AssetMultipleDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DetailView):
    model = Asset
    context_object_name = 'asset'
    template_name = 'asset/asset_multiple_detail.html'

    def test_func(self):
        asset_multiple = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == asset_multiple.owner:
            return True
        return False

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AssetMultipleDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tenants'] = Tenant.objects.filter(asset=context['asset']).order_by('created')
        context['services'] = Service.objects.filter(asset=context['asset']).order_by('created')
        return context
```

I would like to paginate the data that's in **context['tenants]** and **context['services']** and I do not know how to achieve this.

I have done this in their own ListViews using **paginated_by** and got it working without any issues.

I simply would like to know how to paginate a context in a DetailView.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53491725/3345051

Comment: Thank you Hybrid. I saw that one earlier. But it refers to the Partner model in the Partner DetailView. In my case, I am referring to the Tenant and the Service model in Asset DetailView.

Comment: [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) makes pagination as easy as it can get. On any kind of _HTML_ table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the example provided in [django's example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view) on putting pagination in a view. Like this:

```
class AssetMultipleDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DetailView):
    ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AssetMultipleDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        tenants = paginator = Paginator(Tenant.objects.filter(asset=self.get_object()).order_by('created'), 5)  # will show 5 items in one page
        services = Paginator(Service.objects.filter(asset=self.get_object()).order_by('created'), 5)
        context['tenants'] = tenants.get_page(page)
        context['services'] = services.get_page(page)
        return context
```

And update the template like this:

```
// tenants pages
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if tenants.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ tenants.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ tenants.number }} of {{ tenants.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if tennats.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ tenants.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ tenants.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>

// services
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if services.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ services.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ services.number }} of {{ services.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if services.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ services.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ services.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```