# Displaying a list of table entries in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a database table that allows you to enter details about a particular person. How can i then list all the entries of that table to show all the people added to the database.

urls.py

```
url(r'^accounts/loggedin/locations/all/$', 'assessments.views.locations'),
url(r'^accounts/loggedin/locations/get/(?P<location_id>\d+)$',   'assessments.views.location'),
url(r'^accounts/loggedin/locations/create/$', 'assessments.views.create'),
```

models.py

```
class People(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

view.py

```
def people(request):
    return render_to_response('dashboard/people.html', {'people': People.objects.all})
```

people.html

```
<body>
    <h1>People</h1>
    {% for p in people %}
    <h1><a href="/people/get/{{ people.id }}/">{{ people.first_name }}</a></h1>
    {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your output right now? Looks like you should be using `{{ p.first_name }}` inside your for. This way, if your data is correct, it will iterate over all `people` and print an `<h1>` for each person, with the correct name.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I have tried what is suggested but i am getting no output on the screen. Its just bank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems:

- you should call `all()` to get the results, note the `()`:

  ```
  People.objects.all()
  ```
- in the template, you should use `{{ p.first_name }}` instead of `{{ people.first_name }}` since you are iterating over `people` variable which is a [`QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) - a list of objects, basically

Answer (score 0):

it is same question with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106295/django-get-list-of-model-fields)

---

If you had the `Question` model below,

```py
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date published')
```

Through this code, you can see all entries (or fields, features).

```py
fields = Question._meta.get_fields()
```

thanks.