# pass custom queryset to django rest framework nested serializer

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have serializers in the following format:

CounterPartyCompanySerializer:

```
class CounterPartyCompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = ClientCompany
    fields = (
        "id",
        "company_name",
        "address_line1",
    )
    extra_kwargs = {
        "id": {
            "read_only": False,
            "required": False,
        },
    }
```

CounterPartySerializer:

```
class CounterPartySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
company = CounterPartyCompanySerializer()

class Meta:
    model = Client
    fields = (
        "id",
        "company",
        "client_name",
    )
    extra_kwargs = {
        "id": {
            "read_only": False,
            "required": False,
        },
    }
```

and GiftAndEntertainmentSerializer:

```
class GiftAndEntertainmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
counter_party = CounterPartySerializer()

class Meta:
    model = GiftAndEntertainment
    fields = (
        "id",
        "counter_party",
        "value",

    )
```

Case-I :: It works when I do the following:

```
result_list = GiftAndEntertainment.objects.all()

    serializer = GiftAndEntertainmentSerializer(
        result_list, many=True, context={"request": request}
    )
```

But, it doesn't work when I pass the custom queryset like:

```
result_list = GiftAndEntertainment.objects.values(
        "counter_party",
        "value"
    ).annotate(
        total=ExpressionWrapper(Sum("value"), output_field=DecimalField())
    )

    serializer = GiftAndEntertainmentSerializer(
        result_list, many=True, context={"request": request}
    )
```

Here, `"counter_party"` is ForeignKey mapped entity and the queryset passes the `primary-key id` of counter_party entity. I thought the serializer will convert the pk to its corresponding entities like its doing in the case-I but that is not happening automatically. Any help here would save my life. I have spent an entire day trying to achieve this but failed every-single time.

Answer (score 0):

with the help of this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848504/django-get-all-values-group-by-particular-one-field) thread, I was able to achieve this.. What i did was :

First, I prepare GiftAndEntertainment subquery with group by `"counter_party"` where I sum all `value` fields and mark primary key `id` as pk for outer query.

```
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, DecimalField, Subquery, Sum, OuterRef

    group_by = (
        GiftAndEntertainment.objects.values(
            "counter_party"
        )
        .annotate(
            total=ExpressionWrapper(
                Sum("value"), output_field=DecimalField()
            )
        )
        .filter(id=OuterRef("pk"))
    )
```

Then I select all rows from GiftAndEntertainment plus subquery result as `row_value` field.

```
    group_by_with_total = GiftAndEntertainment.objects.annotate(
        row_value=Subquery(group_by.values("total"))
    )

    serializer = GiftAndEntertainmentSerializer(
        group_by_with_total, many=True, context={"request": request}
    )
```

with this, the serializer happily accepted the queryset and even mapped the corresponding entities automatically.