# Django: get object's random attribute

Tags: python, django

Here is my model class:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    photo = models.ImageField()
    games = models.IntegerField()
    minutes = models.IntegerField()
    points = models.IntegerField()
    assists = models.IntegerField()
    rebounds = models.IntegerField()
    steals = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to show one of these atributes randomly. What is the best way to do so?

Comment: create a method to return random attribute, use random function to pick from list of all attributes.  Return it

Comment: What do you mean by showing the attributes? Where and how do you show them?

Comment: I would show the random attribute in template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on [Django: Get list of model fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106295/django-get-list-of-model-fields) and [How to randomly select an item from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-do-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list-using-python) you might write up something like that:

```
import random

class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    photo = models.ImageField()
    games = models.IntegerField()
    minutes = models.IntegerField()
    points = models.IntegerField()
    assists = models.IntegerField()
    rebounds = models.IntegerField()
    steals = models.IntegerField()

    def random_field(self):
        return random.choice([f.name for f in self._meta.get_fields()])
```