# Django get field's name from Field object

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to find out the recommended way of getting a model field's name from a `Field` object.

It seems `field.name` works (which I found out from some SO posts) if `field` is the object name but surprisingly its not mentioned anywhere in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field), so want to know if its still the best way or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems this is the right way to get the model field's name. `field.name` is also used in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/meta/#migrating-from-the-old-api) (see at the bottom of the page) when explaining the migration from the old API to the new model **`_meta`** API:

> MyModel._meta.get_all_field_names() becomes:
>
> ```
> from itertools import chain
> list(set(chain.from_iterable(
>     (field.name, field.attname) if hasattr(field, 'attname') else (field.name,)
>     for field in MyModel._meta.get_fields()
>     # For complete backwards compatibility, you may want to exclude
>     # GenericForeignKey from the results.
>     if not (field.many_to_one and field.related_model is None)
> )))
> ```

and

> ```
> [f.name for f in MyModel._meta.get_fields()]
> ```

Also it feels logically to be so because, on the other hand, when you want a field object [you can get it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/meta/#migrating-from-the-old-api) by its name:

```
f = MyModel._meta.get_field(name)
```

so `f.name` will be the name of the field.

Comment: Thanks - yes, I saw it there too but was wondering why it wasn't in the main Field Options reference. Perhaps just a documentation bug then.

Comment: @Anupam It seems this is the way to get the name. See [this old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3106314/1418794) too.

Comment: @Anupam yes, i think is a lack in documentation