# Dynamically get field name which relates two Django models

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Let's say I have the following Django model:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    children = models.ManyToManyField("Child")

class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I have the `Parent` and `Child` models stored in variables in a script. Given these two models, how can I dynamically get the field name `children` as a string:

```
def get_field_name(model, related_model):
    # what do I need here

get_field_name(Parent, Child)
# "children"
```

Comment: Once see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56713616/12420884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the fields of a model and the type with this command

```
fields = Parent._meta.get_fields()
```

It gives tuple of all the models and `<ManyToManyRel: parent.children>`
Now compare the class and if it has a many to many relation print the attribute.
`fields` gives the class objects. Now you can get the type of the attribute by iterating over the tuple and printing the class name.

```
for i in fields:
     print(i.__class__name)
```

Now you can check for Many to Many field

Answer (score -1):

You can try both of the following lines to get the fields of your model.

```
parent_fields = Parent._meta.fields
# or alternatively
parent_fields = Parent._meta.get_fields()
```

As you'll get a ImmutableList from the output, you'll have to get the field by index number to get the value as string something like that

```
parent_fields[1].attname
```