# iterate horizontally through a Django QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am working with a sql table and want to iterate through it horizontally. I am currently using the django Q library to create query sets:

[image: a preview of the table I am working with]

I am creating and filtering the QuerySets by doing :

`filtered_table = NewTables07.objects.filter(criterion_date & criterion_location)`

The model looks like:

```
class NewTables07(models.Model):

    TestDate = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    Division = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    Library = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    ID = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    mono_full = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    mono_simple = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    mono_brief = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    mono_complex = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    mono_vendor = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    mono_asc = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    mono_added = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'stat_cat1'
```

I am aware that I can iterate through columns by doing something like:

```
for i in filtered_table:
    print(i.<column title>)
```

but if i wanted to iterate through the table horizontally, like through the headers for example : 'ID' then 'Library' 'mono_full' ...

How would I go about doing that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NewTables07._meta.get_fields()` to get all fields in your model and access to field name with `field.name`

[Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3106314/12912476)

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model)

Comment: is there a way to automatically add the fields to my model from my SQL table without having to manually add them?