# Generate Table Columns automatically on Django with view

Tags: python, django

I'm using django and i'm creating a table from the tutorial data.
As i was building my .html i easily got a loop to write the data from my choice instance, but i can't get the same thing to work for the column names.
I saw here how to [get the model fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106295/django-get-list-of-model-fields) but i can't get a loop to do write them for me.

table.html

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% block content%} 
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <p><h3 class="text-primary"> Python Django DataTables </h3></p>
      
<hr style="border-top:1px solid #000; clear:both;" />
<table id = "myTable" class ="table table-bordered">
    <thead class = "alert-warning"> 
        <tr>
<!-- i would like not to have to write those one by one for future projects --> 
            <th> Choice </th> 
            <th> Votes </th>
        </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
<!-- this is the kind of loop I wanted for the columns--> 
        {% for item in qs %} 
        <tr> 
            <td contenteditable='true'>{{item.choice_text}}</td>
            <td>{{item.votes}}</td>  

        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

{% endblock content%}
```

views.py

```
class ChoiceTableView(TemplateView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/table.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["qs"] = Choice.objects.all()
        return context
```

models.py

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Comment: can you add some details on the kind of error or undesired result you are getting?

Comment: The django admin sight does this kind of thing on what it calls a "list view". You could look at its source code to see how they do it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a template that can accomplish a completely automatic printing of header and values, you can do it with a different queryset:

```
context["qs"] = Choice.objects.all().values( 'the', 'fields', 'you', 'want')
```

and in the template, each "object" is a dictionary `{'the':value_of_the, 'fields':..., ...}`. So, `object.keys()` is the headers and `object.values` is the matching data.

So, I think this might work (may need debugging)

```
<table id = "myTable" class ="table table-bordered">
    {% for item in qs %}
      {% if forloop.first %}
         <thead class = "alert-warning"> 
         <tr>
           {% for name in item.keys %} <th>{{name}}</th> {% endfor %}
         </tr>
         </thead>

         <tbody>
      {% endif %}

      <!-- still in the outer loop iterating over qs -->
      <tr> 
        {% for value in item.values %}
           <td {% if forloop.first %}contenteditable='true'{%endif%} >{{value}}</td>
           <!-- the above forloop.first refers to the INNER loop -->
        {% endfor %}
     </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

However, you'll get `choice_text` as a column header, not `choice`, so I feel it would be better to pass the headers in the context:

```
context["qs"] = Choice.objects.all().values( 'choice_text', 'votes')
context["headers"] = ('Choice','Votes')
```

which would also make a more readable template with no necessary use of `forloop.first`. Instead, two outer loops, one for the header and one for the body. If you use `.values_list` instead of `.values` on the queryset, you will get a list-of-lists instead of a list-of-dicts, which then  doesn't need `.values` in the template, just `{% for value in item %}`

Comment: The first solution you proposed work instantly and matches my case so i'm very happy with it !